# Android : Alarm Service not working

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple alarm application where alarm should go off on several days.

I have created a service which registers alarm manager based on data saved in preferences. Everything is working fine except that it does not trigger alarm when app is not running.

**AlarmService.java**

```
   @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //set separate pending intent values for all days
        setIntents();
        // register the alarm manager here
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
        execute();
    }

    private void execute() {

        prefs=getSharedPreferences("user_data_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor=prefs.edit();

        int hour=prefs.getInt("ALARM_HOUR",0);
        int minute=prefs.getInt("ALARM_MINUTE",0);

        if(prefs.getString("ALARM_STATUS","NOT_SET").equals("SET"))
            isAlarmOn=true;
        if(prefs.getString("NOTIFICATION_STATUS","NOT_SET").equals("SET"))
            isNotificationOn=true;

        if (prefs.getBoolean("MON_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.MONDAY,hour,minute,mondayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("TUE_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.TUESDAY,hour,minute,tuesdayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("WED_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.WEDNESDAY,hour,minute,wednesdayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("THU_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.THURSDAY,hour,minute,thursdayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("FRI_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.FRIDAY,hour,minute,fridayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("SAT_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.SATURDAY,hour,minute,saturdayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
        if (prefs.getBoolean("SUN_SET",false)) {
            setAlarmFor(Calendar.SUNDAY,hour,minute,sundayIntent,isAlarmOn,isNotificationOn);
        }
}
    private void setAlarmFor(int weekday, int hour, int minute, PendingIntent pendingIntent, boolean isAlarmOn, boolean isNotificationOn){
        if(isAlarmOn){
            prefEditor.putString("ALARM_STATUS","SET");
            prefEditor.commit();
        }
        if(isNotificationOn){
            prefEditor.putString("NOTIFICATION_STATUS","SET");
            prefEditor.commit();
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,weekday);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        /* Repeating on every week interval */
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                7*24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
    }
    private void setIntents(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        mondayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.MONDAY, intent, 0);
        tuesdayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.TUESDAY, intent, 0);
        wednesdayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.WEDNESDAY, intent, 0);
        thursdayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.THURSDAY, intent, 0);
        fridayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.FRIDAY, intent, 0);
        saturdayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.SATURDAY, intent, 0);
        sundayIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Calendar.SUNDAY, intent, 0);
    }
```

It should trigger AlarmReceiver class that displays alarm.

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("user_data_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Get Status of currently set alarm and notification
    alarmStatus=prefs.getString("ALARM_STATUS","NOT_SET");
    notificationStatus=prefs.getString("NOTIFICATION_STATUS","NOT_SET");
    //Send notification if the notification is set
    if(notificationStatus.equals("SET")){
        Toast.makeText(context, "NOTIFICATION START SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        playNotificationSound(context,getNotificationSound());
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("") // title for notification
                .setContentText("") // message for notification
                .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
        Intent intent_1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 11, intent_1, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        displayNotification(context);
    }
    //Fire Alarm if the Alarm is set
    if(alarmStatus.equals("SET")){
        Toast.makeText(context, "ALARM START SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /** Creating Alarm */
        Intent i = new Intent(context,FitterfoxAlarmActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>

    <service android:name=".AlarmService"></service>
```

Comment: What is the API level of the device or emulator you are testing on?

Comment: Make sure `AlarmReceiver` is declared in the manifest.  If it is not, and is only dynamically registered by some app activity, that would explain why `AlarmReceiver` does not fire when the app is not running.

Comment: I have added manifest code. Is there anything wrong in my declarations?

Comment: Manifest looks okay.  Are you running on KitKat, Lollipop, or Marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of code your service never going to stop it's works for me. "alarmManager.setRepeating" not working in many of the lollipop and marshmallows device once it started then lose control over the service this will help you out.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    piLR = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentLR,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    amLR.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            interval, piLR);
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19
        && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    piLR = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentLR,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    amLR.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, piLR);
} else {
    amLR.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, piLR);
}
```

Comment: setAndAllowWhileIdle: can we use this method for repeat alarm for specific time duration (like 1 minutes)?

Comment: I did check with below code, but alarm not trigger after first initial trigger,  **************************************

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
 loAlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, foInterval, loOperation);
} 
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
 loAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, foTriggerAt, foInterval, loOperation);
} 
else {
 loAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, foTriggerAt, foInterval, loOperation);
}

Answer (score 0):

Starting with KitKat, changes were made to the `AlarmManager` to improve device battery life.  The time at which alarms fire is less exact.  If you want your alarms to fire within minutes of the scheduled time, you will need to change the way you are using `AlarmManager`.

For KitKat (API 19) and later builds, the times specified in `setRepeating()` are  inexact, as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).  The docs also note:

> If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use
>   one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time.

You indicate that the alarms do not fire when the app is not running.  Because the period for your alarms is one week, there can be a large difference between the scheduled time and the actual time the alarm is fired.  The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) indicates:

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time.

I suspect that with your current code, you would eventually see the alarm fire, but might have to wait a very long time after the expected time.

Your revised code will probably need to use [setWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Marshmallow introduced Doze mode, which further changes alarm scheduling.  As @Andy noted in his answer, to get the beavior you want on Marshmallow and later devices, you will need to use [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Two other things that need to be fixed. Your PendingIntents should probably use flag [PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT). In your receiver, the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` belongs on `intent_1`, not `pi`.